# Laravel "save" always creates new record

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using route/model binding to pull up a simple article for a blog. The form loads properly, but when I attempt to edit an existing article and save the form, a new record is always being created. I have `dd($article)` and see that +exists is always set to false. In my url, the "id" is showing up in the uri `admin/write/14"`.

Here is my relevant code:

```php
public function write(Article $article) {

    if (Request::isMethod('post')) {
        $article = self::handleArticleFile($article);
        self::createOrUpdate($article, Input::all());
        return redirect()->route('admin')->with('message', 'Article Created');
    }

    $data = array(
        'article' => $article,
        'editor' => $this->user->id,
        'user' => $this->user,
    );

    return View::make('admin.writeArticle', $data);
}

public function handleArticleFile(Article $article) {

        if (Request::hasFile('article_image')) {
                $file = Request::file('article_image');
                $file->move(base_path() . '/public/images/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
                $article->article_image = 'images/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        }
        return $article;
} 

public function createOrUpdate(Article $article, $input) {

    if ($article) {
        $article->fill($input);
        dd($article);
        $article->save();
    } else {
        $article = Article::create($input);
    }
}
```

My relevant routes:

```php
Route::model('article', 'App\Article');
Route::resource('article', 'App\Article');

Route::get('/', ['as' => 'homepage', 'uses' => 'LandingController@index']);
Route::get('/contact', ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'LandingController@contact']);
Route::post('/send_contact', ['as' => 'sendContact', 'uses' => 'LandingController@sendContactRequest']);
Route::get('/article/{article}', ['as' => 'article', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@index']);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
        Route::any('/write/{article?}', ['as' => 'writeArticle', 'uses' => 'AdminController@write']);
        Route::any('newUser', ['as' => 'newUser', 'uses' => 'AdminController@register']);
        Route::get('/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'AdminController@logout']);
    });
});
```

And my relevant model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model {

    protected $fillable = array(
        'id',
        'title',
        'author',
        'created_at',
        'content',
        'subtitle',
        'article_image',
    );

    protected $table = "articles";

    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    public function articleAuthor() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author');
    }
}
```

Here is the output from `dd($article)`:

```
Article {#195 ▼
  #fillable: array:7 [▶]
  #table: "articles"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #connection: null
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:4 [▶]
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
}
```

Is `fill()` messing it up?

Comment: can you check if `+exists` is already `false` when you `dd($article)` before your `if`-`else`-cascade in `createOrUpdate([..])`?

Comment: It is set to true before the cascade, I think maybe fill() is messing it up?

Comment: @Deena I am using route/model binding, no need to use the conventional  find::($id) here, i will edit

Comment: Looks like your route model binding is wrong. The name should match the route parameters name. So `Route::model('article', 'App\Article');` would be better.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I updated it to show that method. This isn't complicated at all, I suspect you don't understand route/model binding.

Comment: I've had this problem when using a uuid for the primary key - are you using the standard incrementing key or something custom?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using Laravel 5? 5 has method injection, so when requesting an Article, if no matching article is found in the database, laravel will hand you a new blank instance.

The following should solve your problem. The exists property is an eloquent thing that keeps track if a model exists in the database or not, by using that you should be able to determine if the article needs updating or creating.

```
if ($article->exists)
{
    $article->update($input);
}
else
{
    $article = Article::create($input);
}
```

Comment: Can you look at my dd output. I'm aware of what 'exists' does. The problem is that its displaying +exists: false when it shouldn't. 

Also, you don't need to use update, save() will create or update based on exists.